# ASP.NET MVC - how to get the value from a textbox in my View?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, forms

If I have a textbox in my view:

`<div><%= Html.TextBox("Comments", Model.Comments)%></div>`

I want to post the contents of this textbox to the controller with an Ajax call. I only need this one value though, so I don't want to post the whole form back.

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("update", "UpdateComments", 
                new { comments = /* ????? */ }, 
                new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod="POST" })%>
```

How do I get the textbox value?

Comment: Ajax.ActionLink is a helper function, that generates a JS-enabled link, that sends data via AJAX. Because it is generated serverside, and the value is generated on the client side, you can not pass a single value like that. You either have to manually write HTML and JS, or submit a whole form containing this element (and watch out not to nest it inside another form).

Comment: @Alexander: that's been the most helpful comment on here. You should submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax.ActionLink is a helper function, that generates a JS-enabled link, that sends data via AJAX. Because it is generated serverside, and the value is generated on the client side, you can not pass a single value like that. You either have to manually write HTML and JS, or submit a whole form containing this element (and watch out not to nest it inside another form).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than writing server-side ajax code, you should use client-side Ajax (e.g. jQuery) to get the runtime value of the textbox and post that value.

Comment: When you say "should", is there a reason why the way I tried is wrong, or do you just think it's not the easiest way?

Comment: It's just not that easy.  Server code is more about request processing and response sending, the client is responsible for **making** the requests.  In this case, you don't want to use a full-page POST of the form, so an Ajax POST is a suitable alternative (and jQuery makes it easier).

Answer (score 2):

using jQuery, you could retrieve the value in the following manner.

```
$("#Comments").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax in jquery. Like this

```
  function FunctionName() {
        $.Post(URl, function(data) {

        });
    }
```